# python 3 Store values to a list from separated tables in one sqlite database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am a beginner in python.

I have several tables (table1 , table2 , table3 ,...) in my database that they have same column `TotalPrice`.

I want to store `TotalPrice` of all the tables in one list

`TotalPrice` is extracted by this code:

```
for j, v in enumerate(busList):
                mc.execute('SELECT TotalPrice FROM bus'+v+' WHERE Date BETWEEN '+StartDate+' AND '+EndDate+'')
                p = mc.fetchall()
                price = [i[0] for i in p]
```

but i don't know how to store them just in ONE list!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`, it will perform better as it will be a single query sent to the database:

```
mc.execute(' UNION ALL '.join(
    'SELECT TotalPrice FROM bus{} WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ?'.format(v) 
        for v in busList), 
    (StartDate, EndDate) * len(busList),
)
```

Note that this also use parameterization for the dates instead of string interpolation, thus besides also performing better, frees you from quote hell and prevents all forms of injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append()` method of `list` (or `extend`, it depends what do you want - [Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python))

```
price_list = []
for j, v in enumerate(busList):
    mc.execute('SELECT TotalPrice FROM bus'+v+' WHERE Date BETWEEN '+StartDate+' AND '+EndDate+'')
    p = mc.fetchall()
    price_list.append([i[0] for i in p])
```

After that, the `price_list` will contain lists with all prices from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly append to an empty list as suggested by @Andrej or else use this approach

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("select TotalPrice from table1 Union all
                        select TotalPrice from table2;", conn)
myList = df['TotalPrice'].tolist()
```